# Run AppleScript handlers parallel

Tags: macos, asynchronous, applescript

I would like to run this AppleScript handler in parallel two times (so I want two calls of `tillSideBySideWindows("right")` to run asynchronously and not after each other), is there a way to do it?

```
on tillSideBySideWindows(direction)
    tell application "System Events"
        set allVisibleProcessNames to name of processes whose visible is true
        
        repeat with processName in allVisibleProcessNames
            
            set windowsOfCurrentApp to every window of application process processName
            
            repeat with currentWindow in windowsOfCurrentApp
                
                set currentWindowsSize to size of currentWindow
                set currentWindowsWidth to item 1 of currentWindowsSize
                
                set currentWindowsPosition to position of currentWindow
                set currentWindowsLeftPos to item 1 of currentWindowsPosition
                
                if currentWindowsLeftPos = 0 then
                    if direction = "right" then
                        set currentWindowsWidth to currentWindowsWidth + 30
                    else
                        set currentWindowsWidth to currentWindowsWidth - 30
                    end if
                    
                    set currentWindowsHeight to item 2 of currentWindowsSize
                    set winName to name of currentWindow
                    set size of window winName of application process processName to {currentWindowsWidth, currentWindowsHeight}
                end if
                
                if (currentWindowsLeftPos + currentWindowsWidth) = 1680 then
                    set currentWindowsHeight to item 2 of currentWindowsSize
                    
                    if direction = "right" then
                        set currentWindowsLeftPos to currentWindowsLeftPos + 30
                        set currentWindowsWidth to currentWindowsWidth - 30
                    else
                        set currentWindowsLeftPos to currentWindowsLeftPos - 30
                        set currentWindowsWidth to currentWindowsWidth + 30
                    end if
                    
                    set winName to name of currentWindow
                    set position of window winName of application process processName to {currentWindowsLeftPos, 0}
                    set size of window winName of application process processName to {currentWindowsWidth, currentWindowsHeight}
                    get currentWindowsWidth
                end if
            end repeat
        end repeat
    end tell
end tillSideBySideWindows

tillSideBySideWindows("right")
```

Comment: Regular AppleScript is not multi-threaded, but Cocoa can be used via AppleScriptObjC (NSThread for example, but that wouldn't be trivial).  Apple Events may also not be handled properly by the target applications.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, you really helped me.